# Why XmlHttpRequest wait until complete PHP response (proc_open) even with flush?

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, flush

I 'm trying to execute commands (wp cli) with xhr.
My problem is when i call my file deploy.php with the javascript.
**Without JS call the script works, the flush is immediate.**

**When i call deploy.php in a XmlHttpRequest, the response wait until the end of the php execution.**

I try different commands (grep / wp cli / find) but the result is the same.

I work on WSL Debian + Chrome.

```
// PHP
public function liveExecuteCommand($cmd, $ajax = false)
{
        ob_start();

        $descriptorspec = array(
            0 => array("pipe", "r"),
            1 => array("pipe", "w"),
            2 => array("file", "error-output.txt", "a")
        );

        $output = '';
        $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);

        if (is_resource($process)) {

            fwrite($pipes[0], '<?php print_r($_ENV); ?>');
            fclose($pipes[0]);

            while ($s = fread($pipes[1], 8192)) {
                $output .= $s;
                print $s;
                $this->doFlush();
            }

            fclose($pipes[1]);
            $return_value = proc_close($process);

            //echo "La commande a retourné $return_value\n";
        }
        if ($ajax == false) {
            return $output;
        }
}


$obj->liveExecuteCommand($cmd, true);
die();
```

```
// JS
function getLiveStream() {
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = 'https://www.monsite.local/deploy.php';
            ajax.open('GET', url, true);

            ajax.onprogress = function() {
                document.getElementById("xhr_cmd_result").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                console.log('onprogress');
            }
            ajax.onload = function() {
                console.log('onload');
            }
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                document.getElementById("xhr_cmd_result").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                console.log('statechange');
            }
            ajax.send();
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event_loaded) => {
            document.getElementById("xhr_cmd").onclick = getLiveStream;
});
```

In the Google chrome console, the result display all status directly (after 1 min), like the php result.

```
statechange
onprogress
statechange
onprogress
statechange
onprogress
statechange
onload
```

I would like have a console.log **every time that the flush is called**.
No problem when i execute the php file in the browser, the problem is certainly in the javascript.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: The browser has no idea when "flush" is called from your PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain you in simple words.

> Javascript's XMLHttpRequest(AJAX) call will request to server. It will only waits for response from server(final output from your php page), irrespective to internal process of server.